# Removing backslashes from strings in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, regex, string

I have a url in this format:

`http:\/\/example.example.ru\/u82651140\/audio\/song.mp3`

How can I remove the extra "\"s from the string? I have tried string.replace("\","") but that does not seem to do anything. If you could give me a JavaScript regular expression that will catch this, that would also work too. I just need to be able capture this string when it is inside another string.

Comment: One might wonder about why someone would have such a problem.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try:

```
string.replace(/\\\//g, "/");
```

This will specifically match the "\/" pattern so that you don't unintentionally remove any other backslashes that there may be in the URL (e.g. in the hash part).

Comment: This does not fork if there is `/"` inside the string @Ates Goral

Comment: Does not work: try the string "corp\thomas". Will remove "\t".

Comment: @TomaszPlonka You might be getting the impression that it's removing it because `\t` is the escape sequence for the tab character.

Comment: @alper Can you be more specific? Do you mean `"/\""`?

Comment: I believe I meant the string we want to replace contains `/"` your answer does not work

Comment: @alper The question and my answer was about removing backslashes and nothing else. Can you give an example of the full string?

Comment: @alper `/"hello/"` is not valid JS. I'm confused.

Comment: @alper We're trying to remove backslashes (```\```) though. This is a forward slash: `/`.

Comment: ah sorry for misguiding

Answer (score 55):

Try

```
str = str.replace(/\\/g, '');
```

Answer (score 5):

from:
http://knowledge-serve.blogspot.com/2012/08/javascript-remove-all-backslash-from.html

```
function replaceAllBackSlash(targetStr){
    var index=targetStr.indexOf("\\");
    while(index >= 0){
        targetStr=targetStr.replace("\\","");
        index=targetStr.indexOf("\\");
    }
    return targetStr;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Join Two Portions of a Path using
    function join(port1, port2) {
        let p1 = port1.split('/').join('');
        let p2 = port2.split('/').join('');
        let np = p1 + '/' +  p2;
        return np;
    }
    console.log(join("port1/", "/port2"))
```

Answer (score 0):

**"tset\ string \with backslash".split('\\').join('');**

> 'tset string with backslash'