# Javascript regexp backslash removal query

Tags: javascript, regex

I was looking at the responses to the question at [Removing backslashes from strings in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870769/removing-backslashes-from-strings-in-javascript#)
and found that both the responses work,

```
string.replace(/\\\//g, "/");
```

and

```
str = str.replace(/\\/g, '');
```

Could someone please explain the difference between these two and which would be a better choice?

Comment: What exactly is your requirement for this replacement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one unescapes forward slashes specifically (ie replacing `\/` with `/`)

The second just removes all backslashes.

Comment: is that necessary (replacing the forward slashes I mean)?

Answer (score 0):

The second solution `str = str.replace(/\\/g, '');` is wrong, because it will remove single `\` from the string.

Comment: Actually it removes all backslashes from the string. Could you please give the example you tried where it did not?

Comment: The question was to remove \\ (consecutive backslashes) not \ (single backslash).