# How to remove backslah-quote from a JSON response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, replace

I am getting a value returned from an ajax call that looks like \"3/7/2018\". I need to set the value of a jQuery datepicker using this returned value but as is it will set the date to 10/04/2023.

I tried to get rid of backslash-quote using the following but it ignores it and returns the original string. What am I doing wrong here?

```
var uNewDate = newDate.replace(/\\\"/gi, '');
```

here is the entire function:

```
function pageLoad() {
    setStartDate(new Date());
}

// \"3/7/2018\"
function setStartDate(newDate) {debugger
    $('#tbStartDate').unbind();
    $("#tbStartDate").datepicker({
        showOtherMonths: true,
        selectOtherMonths: true,
        showOn: "button",
        defaultDate: new Date(),
        buttonImage: "../assets/images/calendar.gif",
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        buttonText: "Select Start Date",
        option: "mm/dd/yy"
    });
    //var uNewDate = newDate.replace(/\\\"/gi, '');
    $("#tbStartDate").datepicker("setDate", newDate);
}

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "../services/easg.asmx/GetCertItemStartDate",
    cache: false,
    data: certItemID,
}).done(function (result) {debugger
    setStartDate(result.d);
}).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {debugger
    alert(textStatus + ' - ' + errorThrown);
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing backslashes from strings in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870769/removing-backslashes-from-strings-in-javascript)

Comment: Your example works correctly `var test = "\\\"3/7/2018\\\""; test.replace(/\\\"/gi, '');` will return 3/7/2018. Probably you use wrong variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember you are handling JSON data as your response. Special characters are escaped in JSON, like your initial example is showing.

You need to parse it before handling it.

```
JSON.parse("\"3/7/2018\"")

// Result: "3/7/2018"
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't using RegEx, but this will work:

```js
var testDateString = '\"3/7/2018\"';

var newDateString = testDateString.split('\"')
  .join('');

console.log(newDateString);
```