# Replace/remove every backslash in a string

Tags: javascript

I am trying to remove every backslash of a string for an hour, but I cannot make it work.

Here is my string for instance:

> [{\"file\":\"https:\\/n-adsadele.stjkwgjkw.co\/adwq

Here is what I tried:

```
const replaced = toString.replace(String.fromCharCode(92), String.fromCharCode(32));
const replaced = toString.replace("\\\\", "");
const replaced = toString.replace("\\", "");
const replaced = toString.replace(/\\/, "");
```

All of this does absolutely nothing.

Comment: This sounds similar: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1144783/2430549

Comment: Check this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870769/removing-backslashes-from-strings-in-javascript

Comment: `toString.replace("\\", "");` should definitely work

Comment: It doesnt work, but (/\\/g, "") does work, I just forgot the g for global

Comment: str.split("\\").join("")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use regex simply like :

```js
var toString = '[{\"file\":\"https:\\/n-adsadele.stjkwgjkw.co\/adwq';

console.log(toString.replace(/\\/g, ""));
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to say that I tried it as well.

Comment: Ah, I think if it didn't work that may mean the problem comes from something else since you could see that it work well in the snippet.

Comment: Thanks it works, I just forgot the g for global.

Comment: You're welcome, Glad I could help.