# Decode url string in javascript give empty string

Tags: javascript, url, decode

I have this string:

```
http:\/\/www.emptyurl.com\/
```

And i want to change the url to :

```
http://www.emptyurl.com/
```

With :

```
url = url.replace(/\\//gi, "/");
```

But it give me empty string.

Any idea how i can fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing backslashes from strings in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870769/removing-backslashes-from-strings-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You can use decodeURIComponent()

```
var url = 'http:\/\/www.emptyurl.com\/';
url = decodeURIComponent(url);
console.log(url);
```

Comment: Please notice `<>` icon in editor. You can make a snippet using that